# Error dialects = eval(dialects.strip()) File "<string>", line 0 when try to create exe file in PyInstaller

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyinstaller

Console error:

```
  File "C:\Users\semnome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sqlalchemy.py", line 31, in <module>
        dialects = eval(dialects.strip())
      File "<string>", line 0
```

when that happened I usually solved it with:

```
pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade
```

but now it doesn't work anymore, what do I do?

Comment: what code did you run ? maybe it needs some extra settings in file `.spec` with Pyinstaller settings.

Comment: code is huge, but It's basically scraping, BeautifulSoup, mysql connections, sending messages via telegram, selenium....

 and error happens with other .py files too

Comment: create a [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip uninstall sqlalchemy > pip install sqlalchemy

that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it worked for me when I had the same problem

```
pyinstaller App.py --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --exclude-module sqlalchemy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have discovered the issue that causes this error.

I had been having on and off successes and failures which, I now believe, were caused by running pyinstaller or auto-py-to-exe in the wrong folder or with the incorrect virtual environment activated.

I had used the terminal history to get the venv activate command but had failed to notice it was for another similarly named project. When I made sure that my terminal window was in the application root directory and activated the correct virtual environment, then the pyinstaller/auto-py-to-exe processes were consistently successful.